# Unable to access marker position using getPosition() method of Marker class

Tags: android

Unable to access current marker position using getPosition() method of Marker class.

Code:

```
 package com.example.deepak.vibring;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by deepak on 8/2/2015.
 */
public class AddNewLocationActivity extends Activity {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    EditText edtLocation;
    Marker marker;
    List<Address> addressList;
    VibRIngDatabase vibRIngDatabase;
    double latitude, longitude;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    LatLng latLng;
    String locationAddress;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addnewlocation);
        createMapView();// Rendering the Google Map in the fragment
        addMarkerAtCurrent(); // Adding marker at the current location of the device
        mapClick(); // On clicking the map
        vibRIngDatabase = new VibRIngDatabase(this);
    }

    //Display the Google Map inside the fragment
    private void createMapView() {
        /**
         * Catch the null pointer exception that
         * may be thrown when initialising the map
         */
        try {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); //To See my current location

                /**
                 * If the map is still null after attempted initialisation,
                 * show an error to the user
                 */
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error creating map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
            Log.e("mapApp", exception.toString());
        }
    }

    // Adding marker to the current location
    public void addMarkerAtCurrent() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // set map type
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        // Get latitude of the current location
        latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Get longitude of the current location
        longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        String address = getLocationAddress(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(

                new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .title(address));
        // Show the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    }


    public LatLng search(View v) {
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        edtLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLocation);
        String location = edtLocation.getText().toString();
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (location != null) {
            //Geocoder class is used to used to get Latitude and Longitude from location name & vice versa
            //  Toast.makeText(this,"If block entered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // To get address from list<Address>
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            //String featureName = address.getFeatureName();
            String addresssLine = address.getAddressLine(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();
            //  String subLocality = address.getSubLocality();
            String adminArea = address.getAdminArea();
            String locationAddress = addresssLine + " " + locality + " " + adminArea;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address " + locationAddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //To get Latitude & Longitude
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            googleMap.clear();
            //Adding marker to the specified location
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(locationAddress));
            // Show the current location in Google Map
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            // Zoom in the Google Map
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
        }
        return latLng;
    }

    /*public void saveLocation(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "saveLocation called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        edtLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLocation);
        String location_name = edtLocation.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), location_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SQLiteDatabase db = vibRIngDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(VibRIngDatabase.LOCATION_NAME, location_name);
        long id = db.insert(VibRIngDatabase.TABLE_NAME, VibRIngDatabase.LOCATION_NAME, cv);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id = " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (id < 0)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insertion Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insertion Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/

    // Clicking the GoogleMap
    public LatLng mapClick() {
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Getting the Latitude & Longitude of previously touched location
                latLng = arg;
                //Clear the previously touched position
                googleMap.clear();
                latitude = latLng.latitude;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Latitude = " +longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                longitude = latLng.longitude;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Longitude = " +longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String name = getLocationAddress(latitude, longitude);

                //Placing the marker on the touched position
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(locationAddress));
                // Moving camera to the touched position
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                //Animating to touched position
                // googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                // Zoom in the map
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
            }
        });
        return latLng;
    }

    public String getLocationAddress(double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);
        //String featureName = address.getFeatureName();
        String locality = address.getLocality();
        String adminArea = address.getAdminArea();
        locationAddress = addressLine + " " + locality + " " + adminArea;
        return locationAddress;
    }

    // On clicking add button openDialog method will be called
    public void openDialog(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null, false);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Set Mode");
        dialogBuilder.setView(view);
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
        //dialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 800);
        TextView lat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblLatitude);
        TextView longi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblLongitude);
        TextView location_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblLocationName);
        //To retrieve the current position of the marker
        latLng = marker.getPosition();
        double lati1 = latLng.latitude;
        double longi1 = latLng.longitude;
        String name = getLocationAddress(lati1, longi1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        lat.setText(Double.toString(lati1));
        longi.setText(Double.toString(longi1));
        location_name.setText(name);
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.modesRadioGroup);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.vibrationRadioButton:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vibration clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.muteRadioButton:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mute clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.ringingRadioButton:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ringing clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

In this code, I am using Google Map.I have a button named ADD in my activity.
On-click ADD, openDialog() method is called which is responsible for creating a custom Dialog. Everything is working fine here, except the code which will give me the position of marker. After clicking the map or after searching through EditText. I am trying to access the current marker position using getPosition() method of Marker class, but it is not working.

Please check the openDialog() method.

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `marker`? I do not see that happen in your posted code. That makes it always `null`.

Comment: latLng = marker.getPosition();
        double lati1 = latLng.latitude;
        double longi1 = latLng.longitude;

Comment: What your commenting is _retrieving_ a value. According to your posted code, it looks like nothing is ever _assigned_ to the variable, it is always empty.

Comment: Suggest me the changes in the code.

Comment: How can i access the current marker position so that latitude and longitude can be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `marker` variable is always null. You never assign the value to this variable.

I don't understand the full logic of your app, but it looks like you should assign value to your `marker` field after when you trying to add new marker. For instance for `search` method you should change the line:

```
 googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(locationAddress));
```

to

```
marker=googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(locationAddress));
```

Same for other methods.
You should assign the value to your marker before you trying to use it.

Comment: My problem is that there are two ways through which i can locate a position on the Google map. 1.) I can enter a location name in the EditText and search it by cliking Search button which will call search() method .    2.) I can click on Google Map which will call onMapClick() .Everytime i am using one of the mentioned techniques ,older marker will be erased and only one marker will be vivisble .Now i want to use updated latitude and longitude of marker to be displayed in the dialog.How to do it?

Comment: Did u tried to change your code according my answer?

Comment: I changed my code according to your directions.It worked this time.Having different issue now.

Comment: Think it's better to create new question for it. Sure community will help you.

Comment: I have added new issue Andrey.Thanks for your support.